# Steps to Map my Domain in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I just bought an "on demand instance" in AWS, would like to know the steps to map my domain ( www.abc.com ) for my amazon instance to perform the name servers updates, etc ?

I got to know about Route 53 but am sure how the complete workflow will work connecting my domain ( www.abc.com ) to amazon private IP address, please advice?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, this question would be better asked over at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)

Comment: @MattClark But I can see the possible tags here!!

Comment: You could also use the #Facebook tag to ask how to post a status :) I am just saying, you might get a better response asking over there. Or even on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: @MattClark Done!! I ve Posted.

Comment: I would recommend deleting this one to avoid being yelled at for double posting as well... Good luck, hope you find your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty simple, if you have attached a elastic load balancer in front of your instance, you need to map your elastic load balancer's end point. If you only have instances running, attach an elastic IP to it and put that IP in the A record column of the domain name provider.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have One more query. If I buy the reserved instances, the instance's public DNS names will be changed for every system reboot/restart like on-demand instances as i am not much familiar on reserved instances?

Comment: As Jeevan mentioned, you're likely better off using ELB for DNS, that way you can swap out machines behind your ELB without worrying about DNS propagation (unless of course, you're just trying to avoid the cost of ELB)

Comment: You can allocate an elastic IP to your reserved instance even if you init 6 your instance, you can run a start-up script during reboot to make sure you attach the same IP to your instance